# Android equivalent of WebClient in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, android, webclient

I have a fairly basic application that I wrote in C# NET some time ago and would like to rewrite it for the Android platform. It just uses an API exposed by some web software, and I can access it with just a WebClient in .NET.

```
WebClient myClient = new WebClient();

//Prepare a Name/Value Collection to hold the post values
NameValueCollection form = new NameValueCollection();
form.Add("username", "bob");
form.Add("password", GetMD5Hash("mypass"));
form.Add("action", "getusers");

// POST data and read response
Byte[] responseData = myClient.UploadValues("https://mysite.com/api.php", form);
string strResponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseData);
```

I found the WebKit (`android.webkit` | Android Developers) but just from quick looking that doesn't seem appropriate.

Does anyone have any sample code of how to port this over?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be an equivalent:

```
List<NameValuePair> form = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "bob");
// etc...

// Post data to the server
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://mysite.com/api.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

To summarize [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) could replace your WebClient. Then you have to use either [HttpPost](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) for posting data or [HttpGet](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html) for retrieving data. There are some tutorials that you can read to help you understand how you could use these classes like this [one](http://remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a20/Android-A-Quick-and-Dirty-Http-Client.html).